# Sticky Table Header in Plain JS

Tags: javascript, html-table

I wrote a code for **sticky/fixed table header**. I am bit confused with my coding, though it does my job. I know there are many jQuery codes available. But I wanted to do it in plain **JS** with **IE** support. Now I want to see is there anything wrong/abuse of language in my code. If there any efficient code I can implement here, please let me know.

### Here my code:

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
table = [].slice.call(table);
var clonedTable = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  for (i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    function init() {
      var wrapper = document.createElement("div"),
        clone = table[i].cloneNode(true),
        parent = table[i].parentNode;
      clone.classList.add("fixed");
      wrapper.classList.add("container");

      for (let j = 0; j < clone.tBodies.length; j++) {
        clone.removeChild(clone.tBodies[j]);
      }
      wrapper.appendChild(clone);
      parent.insertBefore(wrapper, table[i]);
      wrapper.appendChild(table[i]);
      clonedTable.push(clone);

      resizeFixed();
    }

    function resizeFixed() {
      var ths = this.clonedTable[i].querySelectorAll('th'),
        ths2 = table[i].querySelectorAll('th');
      for (var u = 0; u < ths.length; u++) {
        ths[u].style.width = ths2[u].offsetWidth + 'px';
      }
    }

    init();
  }

});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  for (let t = 0; t < clonedTable.length; t++) {
    var ths = this.clonedTable[t].querySelectorAll('th'),
      ths2 = table[t].querySelectorAll('th');
    for (var u = 0; u < ths.length; u++) {
      ths[u].style.width = ths2[u].offsetWidth + 'px';
    }
  }
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var offset = this.pageYOffset;
  for (var n = 0; n < table.length; n++) {
    var tableOffsetTop = table[n].offsetTop,
      tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + table[n].offsetHeight - table[n].tHead.offsetHeight;

    if (offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom)
      clonedTable[n].style.display = 'none';

    else if (offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom)
      clonedTable[n].style.display = 'table';
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: .9em normal Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #34495E;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.blue {
  border: 2px solid #1ABC9C;
}

.blue thead {
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
}

.purple {
  border: 2px solid #9B59B6;
}

.purple thead {
  background: #9B59B6;
}

thead {
  color: white;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background: #f1f5f7;
  /* color:#FFFFFF; */
}

.fixed {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="purple">
  <thead>
    <th>Colored Text</th>
    <th>Color Preview</th>
    <th>Color Name</th>
    <th>Hex Value</th>
    <th>RGB Value</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table class="blue">
  <thead>
    <th>Colored Text</th>
    <th>Color Preview</th>
    <th>Color Name</th>
    <th>Hex Value</th>
    <th>RGB Value</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Fuscia</td>
      <td>#f1a4b1</td>
      <td>102, 74, 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Print</td>
      <td>#ea12fb</td>
      <td>41, 45, 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Pink</td>
      <td>#aa12fa</td>
      <td>55, 84, 100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Gold</td>
      <td>#abcdef</td>
      <td>120, 210, 43</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have any known issues? Or are you just asking for people to review your code? (If so, that would be better suited for [the code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: @DBS I am done with this code. I have no issues. I willing to get review. If anything can be updated here for optimizing this process.